Meaning of .* in negative lookahead in regular expression
There is a part of the regular expression that I don't understand.
text: 123google
.*(?!google)
result :
Why does '123Google' match?
(.*)(?!google)
If it's confirmed in the capture group, .* It's not "123". It's "123 google".
Does it match because there is no "g" after "123google"?
Or is there another reason why I didn't think about it?
That's what I'm going to do .* Does it always mean all strings before looking forward negatively?
(.*)(?=google)
In Positive Look Ahead, .* matches '123' rather than a full string.
(.*)(?!google)
In negative lookahead, why does .* match the entire string? What characters must precede the look around expression?
\d+(?!google)
Why is only '12' matched in '123google'?
(?!.*google).*
Why only the back "o o g l e" matches in "123google"?
I'd like to know the reason and the principle.

See: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html and https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

.*(?!google) (.*)(?!google) (.*)(?=google) etc

I really recommend reading what's in the description on the right panel when you look at the Regex101 links shared by jhnc (you can read it when closing the debugger). In case you still don't understand the first case: .* will try to match as many characters as possible, and it happens that '123Google' is not directly followed by 'google', so it makes sense, regexes can be counter intuitive

.*(?!google): .* matches 123google, which isn't followed by google. // .*(?=google): .* originally matches 123google, but then (?=google) fails. After some backtracking, .* ends up matching 123. // The others are variations of this.

(?!.*google)*: This doesn't match "the back "o o g l e" in '123google'" as you claim. It successfully matches 0 characters at position 0. It's more interesting that (?!.*google) matches 0 characters at position 4 (assuming an unanchored search). That because it can't match at position zero, so the regex engine will try matching at position 1. It doesn't match there either. But it will eventually match when the engine starts at position 4.
